# Adding tables dynamically to a database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am writing an app which logs the GPS data in a database. Each time the user starts logging, I'd like to create a new table and save the data in that table. When the user stops logging, the table is closed. So the next time the user starts the app a new table should be created in the current database. How can I add tables dynamically to the current database?

In several different places I have read it is not a good idea to add tables or columns dynamically to a database. But why? and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the schema dynamically makes data migrations you might want to perform on app update much harder. You'll also have to keep track of the created table names, which is doable, but probably completely unnecessary.

I'd say that what you really need is something like a `session_id` column in the GPS data table.

Comment: Oh, yeah. That's makes a TON of sense. I have been trying to do this for 2 whole days. Thanks :)
But, how can I actually add tables dynamically? Is it possible?